# Area of Overlap between two rotated squares?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

A unit square is rotated around one vertex by an angle $\alpha,$ where $0^\circ < \alpha < 90^\circ$ and $\cos \alpha = \frac{4}{5}.$ Find the area of the shaded region that is common to both squares.

[image]

Comment: You **have** to show what you have attempted.

Comment: Let $\beta = \frac {\pi}{2} - \alpha.$  You should be able to find the shaded area in terms of a function of $\frac {\beta}{2}$  Then apply what half angle formula you need to get to the final answer.

Comment: Or extend the left side of the rotated square such that it meets the horizontal line. Then compute the difference between the areas of two triangles to find the area of the shaded region.

Answer (score 3):

We can find the unshaded area and subtract it from the area of the square.
[image]

Comment: I have provided a solution that is very complementary of yours, in that it uses the particular value of $\alpha$ right at the end...

Comment: @JeanMarie, Yes I saw it, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider for the moment a general rotation angle $\alpha$ (we will give it its specific value at the end); let us denote by $A$ the rotation center and by  $B,C,D$ the other vertices of the quadrilateral in grey, in the direct sense. Thus $AC$ is a symmetry axis of the figure.

Let us denote  right triangle $ABC$ by $\Delta$.

Its area is  $\tfrac12 AB.BC=\tfrac12 \tan \beta$, where $\beta$ is the angle in $A$ in triangle $\Delta$ i.e.,

$$\beta:=\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$$

Thus, the whole gray area is:

$$\tag{1}\tan \beta=\tan(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\alpha}{2})=\dfrac{1-\tan \tfrac{\alpha}2}{1-\tan \tfrac{\alpha}2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin \alpha}{1+\sin \alpha}}=\frac{1-\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$$

using rather standard formulas that can be found for instance in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

(The graphical representation of the overlapping area as a function of $\alpha$ is displayed below).

Let us now, finally, consider the case of $\alpha$ defined by $\cos \alpha=\tfrac45$, giving $\sin \alpha=\sqrt{1-(\cos \alpha)^2}=\tfrac35$ ; plugging these values in  relationship (1) gives the result:

> $$\dfrac{1-\tfrac35}{\tfrac45}=\dfrac12$$

[image]

Fig. 1: Overlapping area as a function of angle $\alpha$ : an almost linearly decreasing function, ending at $0$ when $\alpha = \tfrac{\pi}{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

The shaded area is symmetric so you need to calculate half of its surface which is a right triangle and multiply it by 2. $\cos(\alpha)={4\over 5}\to\cos({\alpha\over 2})={3\over\sqrt {10}}$ and $\sin({\alpha\over 2})={1\over\sqrt {10}}$. Then the right triangle has legs $a=tan({{\pi\over 4 }-{\alpha\over2}})$ and $b=1$ which using geometrical relations gives us:

$\Large a={{1-\tan({\alpha\over 2})}\over{1+\tan({\alpha\over 2})}}={{\cos({\alpha\over 2})}-{\sin({\alpha\over 2})}\over{{\cos({\alpha\over 2})}+{\sin({\alpha\over 2})}}}$

by substitution we have $a={1\over 2}$ and $b=1$ and the shaded area is $S=ab={1\over 2}$

Comment: You should add some motivation to your answer.

Comment: Sorry for summarization!........Here is the answer......

Comment: [+1] I just modified my answer, and I see we are on the same tracks !