# All possible values of coordinate k such that triangle ABC is a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, analytic-geometry

Determine all values of $k$ for which the points $A = (1,2),$ $B = (11,2),$ and $C = (k,6)$ form the vertices of a right-angled triangle.

Comment: Are integer values of $k$ required, or any real values?

Comment: The raw question, without comments, without desire to enter into an exchange with us ... As you are not new on the site, you should know that we want askers to show that they have worked on the issue.

Comment: Now, I remember, it's not the first time that you do not want to enter into contact: you are the author of "Area of Overlap between two rotated squares?" (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2592345) for which many valuable answers had been given : not a single comment from you !

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If the right angle is at $A$, $k=1$.

If the right angle is at $B$, $k=11$.

If the right angle is at $C$, then $AC\perp BC$. We can find $k$ easily by considering the product of the slopes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

a) If $\triangle ABC$ is riht-angled at $A$, then $AC$ is vertical, i.e. $k=1$.

b) If $\triangle ABC$ is riht-angled at $B$, then $BC$ is vertical, i.e. $k=11$.

c) If $\triangle ABC$ is riht-angled at $C$, then $m_{BC}m_{CA}=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$AB^2=100,BC^2=(k-11)^2+4^2,AC^2=(k-1)^2+4^2$$ and solving the equation $$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2$$ for $k$ we get $$k_1=3$$ or $$k_2=9$$ can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{AB}=(10,0)$ and we know that either $\vec{AC}=(k-1,4)$ or $\vec{BC}=(k-11,4)$ must be orthogonal to $\vec{AB}$, or that $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{BC}$ are orthogonal.

$0=\langle(10,0),(k-1,4)\rangle=10(k-1)$ iff $k=1$ and

$0=\langle(10,0),(k-11,4)\rangle=10(k-11)$ iff $k=11$ and

$0=\langle(k-1,4),(k-11,4)\rangle=k^2-12k+11+16=(k-3)(k-9)=0$ iff $k=3$ or $k=9$.

So $k$ is either $1$, $3$, $9$ or $11$.

Answer (score 0):

If the right angle is at $A$, then $k=1$. If the right angle is at $B$, then $k=11$. If the right angle is at $C$, then the product of the slope of $AC$ and $BC$, is $-1$, or, $$\frac{6-2}{k-1}\cdot\frac{6-2}{k-11}=-1$$
Sobe this quadratic in $k$ to get the values of $k$ for which the right angle is at $C$.